# Flutter : Question about Futures and async function

Tags: asynchronous, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, future

I have several questions regarding the use of Futures in dart. Let's say I am working with a firestore and I have a function like this to update users's info :

```
void updateOldUser(User oldUser,String newInfo){
DocumentReference userToUpdateRef = userRef.document(oldUser.id);
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
DocumentSnapshot userToUpdateSnapshot = await transaction.get(userToUpdateRef);
  if(userToUpdateSnapshot.exists){
    await transaction.update(
      userToUpdateSnapshot.reference, userToUpdateSnapshot.data[newInfo] + 1
    ).catchError((e)=> print(e));
  }
});
```

}

My question is : does it need to return a future since runTransaction is Future. It seems to work fine without it but to me it feels like it should return a "Future void" in order to be able to await updateOldUser when I use it. But when I turn it into a "Future void"  and then end the function body with 'return;' I have an error saying 'expected a value after return'.
But what I really don't understand is that with another similar code :

```
Future<void> updateUserPhoto(User user,File userPhoto) async {
String photoUrl = await  uploadImage(user.id,userPhoto);
DocumentReference userToUpdateRef = userRef.document(user.id);
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction transaction) async {
  DocumentSnapshot userToUpdateSnapshot = await transaction.get(userToUpdateRef);
  if(userToUpdateSnapshot.exists){
    await transaction.update(
      userToUpdateSnapshot.reference, {
      'photoUrl' : photoUrl
      }
    ).catchError((e)=> print(e));
  }
});
return;
```

}

I don't get this error and It work fine also. Why ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> does it need to return a future

If you want the caller to be able to await the completion of the function, then the return type should be `Future<...>` (like `Future<void>` if there is no concrete return value, or `Future<int>` if the result is an integer value, ...)

For fire-and-forget `async` functions you can use `void`, but that is rather uncommon. 
If the return type is `Future<...>` the caller can still decide not to wait for completion anyway.

> But when I turn it into a "Future void" and then end the function body with 'return;'

If you use `async`, a `Future` is returned implicitly at the end of the method.

If you do **not** use `async`, you need to return a `Future` like

```
return doSomething.then((v) => doSomethingElse());
```